# Scheduling - Assigning jobs to the most efficient worker

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

This was asked by a friend of mine. I had no previous context, so I want to know what type of algorithm this problem belongs to. Any hint or suggestions will do.

Suppose we have a group of N workers working at a car assembly line. Each worker can do 3 types of work, and their skills rated from 1 to 10. For example, Worker1's "paint surface" efficiency is rated 8, but "assemble engine" efficiency is only rated 5.

The manager has a list of M jobs defined by start time, duration, job type, and importance, rated from 0 to 1. Each worker can only work on 1 job at a time, and 1 job can be worked by 1 worker. How can the managers assign the jobs properly to get maximum output?

The maximum output for a job = worker skill rating * job importance * duration.

For example, we have workers {w1, w2}

```
w1: paint_skill = 9, engine_skill = 8

w2: paint_skill = 10,engine_skill = 5
```

We have jobs {j1, j2}

```
j1: paint job,  start_time = 0, duration = 10, importance = 0.5

j2: engine job, start_time = 3, duration = 10, importance = 0.9
```

We should assign w1 to j2, and w2 to j1. output = 8 * 10 * 0.5 + 10 * 10 * 0.9 = 40 + 90 = 130

A greedy solution that matches the next available worker with the next job is clearly sub-optimal, as in the example we could have matched w1 to j1, which is not optimal.

A exhaustive brute-force solution would guarantee the best output, but will use exponentially more time to compute with large job lists.

How can this problem be approached?

Comment: What should we do if there's no workers that can start a job in-time? for example we have 2 workers and 2 jobs that starts at `time = 0`?

Comment: @FalconUA in that case we don't do the job, and lose the profit from it

Comment: This is similar to *Bin Packing* and *Job Shop Scheduling*, both of which are NP-complete|NP-hard. A greedy algorithm (such as First Fit Decreasing) and a Local search (such as Tabu Search or Late Acceptance) works very well on it (see [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c)).